# Excluding multiple values in t-sql

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a very large sql statement I have to make a modification to. In one of the tables there are four int columns and I have to exclude 2 sets. If I just want to exclude the values for one table it is pretty simple, use an except statement. I can do this:

```
select *
from Table Z
except(
select *
from Table Z
where (A= 2 and B= 10 and C= 3 and D= 90) 
or (A= 2 and B= 17 and C= 100 and D= 90))
```

However I can't get it to work using a where statement. I only want those two sets of combinations excluded. In the real statement there is a join with six different tables and all kinds of case statements in the select.

I have tried a few things and nothing seems to work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: If EXCEPT isn't working and "In the real statement there is a join with six different tables and all kinds of case statements in the select.", you probably need to take a closer look at the `JOIN`s, any other `WHERE` clauses you have, and possibly provide them here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why the complex `EXCEPT`? Doesn't this work?:

```
SELECT  *
FROM Table Z
WHERE NOT (  ( A= 2 and B= 10 and C= 3 and D= 90) 
          OR ( A= 2 and B= 17 and C= 100 and D= 90)
          )
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply use the `NOT` operator:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table Z 
 WHERE NOT ((A = 2 and B = 10 and C = 3 and D = 90)  
            OR (A = 2 and B = 17 and C = 100 and D = 90))
```

or, applying [De Morgan's laws](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws),

```
SELECT * 
  FROM Table Z 
 WHERE (NOT (A = 2 and B = 10 and C = 3 and D = 90))
   AND (NOT (A = 2 and B = 17 and C = 100 and D = 90))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try NOT IN e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Table1 WHERE Table1.ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM Table1 WHERE Somewhereclause)
```

In your case:

```
select *
from Table Z
WHERE Z.ID NOT IN (
select ID
from Table Z
where (A= 2 and B= 10 and C= 3 and D= 90) 
or (A= 2 and B= 17 and C= 100 and D= 90))
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are two ways:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE Z 
    WHERE Z.ID NOT IN 
    (SELECT ID FROM TABLE Z WHERE (A= 2 AND B= 10 AND C= 3 AND D= 90) OR (A= 2 AND B= 17 AND C= 100 AND D= 90))
```

This second way may perform a little better...NOT INs can be problematic:

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE Z
    LEFT JOIN TABLE Z2
    ON 
    Z.Id = Z2.ID
    WHERE (Z2.A= 2 AND Z2.B= 10 AND Z2.C= 3 AND Z2.D= 90) OR (Z2.A= 2 AND Z2.B= 17 AND Z2.C= 100 AND Z2.D= 90)) WHERE Z2 IS NOT NULL
```

Keep a close eye on the second one...I'm not 100% sure on it. I'd try the first one first and only use the second one if you have performance problems.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you the same results as your example query, and only requires one SELECT statement.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_Z
WHERE NOT (A= 2 and B= 10 and C= 3 and D= 90) 
   AND NOT (A= 2 and B= 17 and C= 100 and D= 90)
```